# Grafana annotations with ElasticSearch always on the right (on the current date and time)

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I am using grafana 3.1 on maxOs Sierra and I use elasticsearch as datasource.

I have set my mapping on ES: 
"properties" : {
    "gasLeak" : {
        "type" :    "boolean"
    },
    "gasConsumption" : {
        "type" :    "boolean"
    },
    "electricityConsumption" : {
        "type" :    "boolean"
    }
}

I have also a timestamp filed name alert.timestamp which is typed as a date on ES.

Everytime an alert is triggered, I add an entry into the ES index. There are 3 alerts type as shown in the mapping.

Now, on grafana, I have my dashboard with a graph panel. On this graph I want to display the annotation which represents alerts.
I have configured my alert as follow:
[Grafana annotation config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAMqq.png)

But then on my graph, the annotation is displayed aheah of my measures: it is always on the right at the current datetime:
[Issue on graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vd9k9.png)

Am I configuring the annoation wrongly? Do I need other configuration on ES side?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why it was not working: in the "field mapping" part, the filed "Time" has to be "timestamp"...

I used to put alert.timestamp and when I updated my ES document structure using timestamp instead of alert.timestamp as field name, after updating the field in grafana, it worked.

I also added the field "desc" and "tags" in my ES document so maybe it is also related, I did not dig that.

Hope this could help someone someday.